# How can I make cbindgen not include stdlib.h?

Tags: rust, embedded

I am working in an embedded project using a custom libc. I am trying to integrate Rust into the project and I am not allowed to include the stdlib.h, I am using cbindgen to generate the header file for the rust library and I would like to know how can I make it not include the libc?

Comment: Assuming you don't use `std` (only `core` and possibly `alloc`), Rust does not link libc.

Comment: I know, my question was maybie unclear. I am generating a header file using the cbindgen crate. And this crate includes stdlib by default in the header file it generates. I was wondering if there is a way to disable that

Comment: If the question is unclear, you should edit it to make it clear rather then clarify in comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a cbindgen.toml file and set in it:

```ini
# Whether cbindgen's default C/C++ standard imports should be suppressed. These
# imports are included by default because our generated headers tend to require
# them (e.g. for uint32_t). Currently, the generated imports are:
#
# * for C: <stdarg.h>, <stdbool.h>, <stdint.h>, <stdlib.h>, <uchar.h>
#
# * for C++: <cstdarg>, <cstdint>, <cstdlib>, <new>, <cassert> (depending on config)
#
# default: false
no_includes = true
```

https://github.com/mozilla/cbindgen/blob/master/docs.md.

Comment: Thanks, I dindt see there was a function for that. To complete the awnser: pub fn with_no_includes(self) -> Builder